# Mock an instance of a module NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mocking, sinon

How can I mock an instance of a `module` in a method that I'm testing?

**Method example:**

```
var item = require('item'); // module to mock

// underTest.js
module.exports = {

    parse: function(model) {
       return new item(model).parse();
    }

}
```

I would like mock the `item` module and assert that the `parse` method has been called.

My test suite use `sinon` and `mocha` any example to achieve that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can create a Mock through extending the prototype

```
// yourmock.js
var item = require("item")

exports = item
exports.parse = function() {
   //Override method
}
```

**EDIT**

An example. You have a NodeJS application that request an external API. For example we have Stripe to complete a credit card payment. This payment is done by the payment.js object and in there you have a `processPayment` method. You expect a `boolean` to come back inside a callback.

The original file could look like:

```
// payment.js
exports.processPayment = function(credicardNumber, cvc, expiration, callBack) {
   // logic here, that requests the Stripe API
   // A long time processing and requesting etc.
   callback(err, boolean)
}
```

Because you want to have no problems with handling stripe during tests, you need to mock this function so that it can be used without any delays of requesting servers.

What you can do is use the same functionality, but you take over the functions that request the server. So in the real environment you expect a callback with an Error and boolean and this mock will provide you that.

```
// paymentMock.js
var payment = require('./payment');

// exports everything what normally is inside the payment.js functionality
exports = payment

// override the functionality that is requesting the stripe server
exports.processPayment = function(creditCardNumber, cvc, expirationDate, callBack) {
   // now just return the callback withouth having any problems with requesting Stripe
   callBack(null, true);
}
```

Is this maybe easier for you to understand?

Comment: Thanks a lot paul, but I'm relatively new to testing in node, may you give me an example on how do you test that little method please. Do you think the right way is to overwrite his default method to make an expectation? Cheerse

Comment: @Fabrizio I have edited the answer, maybe you will get more sense of what I tried to explain you?